# Calling a function whose arguments should be structure instances

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

Given the following code, what would by the syntax for calling the function `dist`?

```
(defstruct coord 
  x 
  y)

(defstruct line 
  (point1 :type coord) 
  (point2 :type coord) )


(defun dist (point1 point2)
  (sqrt (+ (square (- (coord-x point1) (coord-x point2)))
           (square (- (coord-y point1) (coord-y point2))))))

(defun square (x) (* x x))
```

Comment: In the code you've shown, you're already calling functions `sqrt`, `+`, `square`, `-`, `coord-x`, `coord-y`, and `*`.  Are you having some trouble calling `dist` in the same fashion?  It's not really clear what you're asking, given that you've already got the rest of this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beautiful thing about languages in the Lisp family is the (relatively) uniform syntax.  Just like you call the function `square` by writing `(square n)` or `*` by `(* n1 n2 ...)`, you call `dist`, which takes two arguments with, `(dist point1 point2)`.  In context, this might be something like:

```
(let ((point1 (make-coord …))
      (point2 …))
  (dist point1 point2))
```

Comment: Thank you. For whatever reason this code would throw type errors when I ran it, but using setf method to globalize the variables and then calling as you described worked like a charm.